# WIF 4.5 Claim Value - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, wif, claims-based-identity, claims

I'm using the new WIF 4.5 SDK, but i have the same annoying exception that with LINQ is resolved with .FirstorDefault()

```
 var claimEmail = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value;
```

The problem here is that Windows Live ID have no email value in the claim, so if an user log in with a live ID i have a **NullReferenceException - Object reference not set to an instance of an object**. I also tried;

```
var claimEmail = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value.FirstorDefault();
```

without success

How can i return NULL or "" if ther's no email in the claim?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a `FirstOrDefault` shortcut in the `ClaimsPrincipal` class, but you can always just use LINQ to iterate the list of claims to do the same thing:

```
var claimEmail = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or you can just put in a check to make sure the Claim isn't NULL:

```
var claimEmail = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email);
var email = (claimEmail == null ? string.Empty : claimEmail.Value);
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: The first statement is valid, even if do not take the value, but i can parse the string to take it. Thank you Sir!
I also resolved inserting the code in a try/catch block but was not an elegant way

Comment: What has to be adjusted that email is not null?